# A linear transformation whose domain has higher dimension than the target space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I have a doubt in this question. I would like to check if my answer for letter a is correct and a hint for letter b.

Let $T:U\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation where $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces such that $\dim_\mathbb{K}V<\dim_\mathbb{K}U < \infty$.

a) Prove the existence of a nonzero element $u \in U$ such that $T(u) = 0$.

b) Let $\mathbb{B}$ be an arbitrary basis of $U$. Does there always exists a vector $u \in \mathbb{B}$ such that $T(u) = 0$? Prove or give a counterexample.

My attempt:

a) Let $\dim_\mathbb{K}V = n$, $\dim_\mathbb{K}U = m$ and $B_U= \{ u_1, ..., u_n\}$ be a basis of U, so

$u$ = $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i u_i \Longrightarrow T(u)  =  \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i T(u_i)$

$n = \dim_\mathbb{K}V < dim_\mathbb{K}U = m$, so all lineary independent sets in $V$ have at most 'n' elements, but

$A = \{ T(u_1), ..., T(u_m) \}$ has #$A = m > n$, therefore $A$ is lineary dependent. In other words,

$\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i T(u_i) = 0$ for some $0<i<m+1$. So, there exists a nonzero $u \in U$ such that $T(u) = 0$.

b)

For this question I have no  idea, but I think I need to use my development in 'a'.

Comment: yes $A$ is not a basis for $V$ but you can't say that sum equals zero.

Comment: Be sure to mention that you must pick your $\alpha_i$ appropriately. You fixed $u$ earlier in the problem than you should.

Comment: In part b), given $v \in V$, you choose $T$ so that it sends every element of $\mathbb B$ to $v$, which gives a counterexample when $v \neq 0$.

Comment: For part (b), a linear transformation is entirely determined by its action on a basis of $U$, and its action on the basis vectors can be chosen arbitrarily. You can use this to define a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct your (a). Any vector in $U$ can be written as $\sum \alpha_i u_i$ and the corresponding image under $T$ can then be written as $\sum \alpha_i T(u_i)$. As you noted correctly $\{ T(u_1), \dots T(u_n) \}$ must be linearly dependent. By definition, this implies the existence of some scalars $\beta_1, \dots , \beta_n$, not all equal to $0$, such that $\sum \beta_i T(u_i) = 0$. And since $T$ is linear this gives $T(\sum \beta_i u_i) = 0$, i.e. if you **define** $u := \sum \beta_i u_i$, then $T(u) = 0$ and $u \neq 0$, since some $\beta_j$ is nonzero.

Another way to prove it, similar to the answer of @Brian Fitzpatrick, is to go by contradiction. Assume that no such $u$ exists. This implies that $T$ is injective, i.e. $V$ would contain a subspace, namely $T(U)$, which has higher dimension than $V$.

Question (b) has been answered in the comments.

Comment: can I say that $\beta_i = \alpha_i$ for all $i$? Because I can't see the difference between I wrote and you wrote for answer in letter 'a'

Comment: @George See Eric Thoma’s comment to your question. Linear dependence of $\{T(\alpha_iu_i)\}$ doesn’t let you conclude that the $\alpha_i$ are the coefficients that make their sum zero. E.g., take $T:(x,y)\mapsto(x-y)$. Then $T(3,2)=T(3,0)+T(0,2)=3-2$; $3$ and $2$ are linearly dependent, but $3-2\ne0$.

Comment: @M.U., so $\alpha_i$ are generic coefficients that generate T(u) and $\beta_i$ are specific coefficents such that $\sum^n_{i=1} \beta_i T(u_i)$ = $0$.?

In your example, $\alpha_1$ = 3 and $\alpha_2$ = 2, but in $T(7,7)$ = $T(7,0) + T(0,7)$ = $3 - 3$ = $0$. $\beta_1 = \beta_2$ = $7$?

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Your first sentence is exactly what it is about! btw the example in the comment is from @amd.

Comment: I understood now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $T:U\to V$ is a linear map where $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces such that $\dim(V)<\dim(U)$.

Here's a more efficient solution to (*a*) using the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Note that the rank-nullity theorem implies that
$$
\dim\bigl(\ker T\bigr)=\dim(U)-\dim\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}\bigl(\im T\bigr)\tag{1}
$$
But $\im(T)$ is a subspace of $V$ so 
$$
\dim\bigl(\im T\bigr)\leq\dim V\tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2) gives
$$
\dim\bigl(\ker T\bigr)\geq\dim(U)-\dim(V)\tag{3}
$$
But the inequality $\dim(V)<\dim(U)$ implies that $\dim(U)-\dim(V)>0$. Thus (3) gives
$$
\dim\bigl(\ker T\bigr)>0
$$
In particular, this implies that there exists a nonzero $u\in U$ such that $T(u)=\mathbf 0$.

To address (*b*) let's write down some relevant examples. Linear maps $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ are always of the form $T(x,y)=ax+by$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$. We also have the *standard basis* $\{e_1=(1,0),e_2=(0,1)\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$. Can you find $a$ and $b$ such that $T(e_1)\neq0$ and $T(e_2)\neq 0$?

Comment: I disagree that the OP's solution for (a) looks fine.